# Calculating the size of a list of files without using find / -exec

Tags: bash

Sure, `find -exec` allows me to used `stat` to get file size, and a tiny Python one-liner to sum that:

`find . -name "*.sh" -exec stat -f '%z' {} \; | python -c'import sys; print sum(int(x) for x in sys.stdin)'`

There could be a use of `bc`, I guess, to make that more bash-like.

However, (**The question**), I already have a list of files, `find -exec` is out. How do I tersely and elegantly get the file sizes in a pipe.  I could use a `xargs` and `du|cut` pipeline, but despite `-s` on xargs, I run the risk of blowing up the command length or having to over-allocate to the tune of gigabytes.

I'm hoping for something that can calculate disk usage and do so in a standard-in centric way:

`cat myList.txt -exec stat -f '%z' {} \; | python -c'import sys; print sum(int(x) for x in sys.stdin)'`

Cat doesn't have an -exec though :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a pipe with `xargs du` and `awk`:

```
xargs -a file.list du -b | awk '{t+=$1}END{print t}'
```

That gives you the accumulated size in bytes.

Comment: In this configuration, does xargs have an upper limit on command length? I mean by doing -a rather than having xargs pull from standard in.

I should said before, but I'm on a Mac, and that doesn't have the -a option, sadly.